# The relationship between unsatisfiable and (logical) entailment.

Tags: logic

In Goldrei's "Propositional and Predicate Calculus" Pg. 106 (Theorem 3.10), he offers the following: (If $\Gamma \models\theta$, then $\Gamma \vdash \theta$) $\leftrightarrow$ (If $\Delta$ is consistent, then $\Delta$ is satisfiable)

In proving from left to right, he aims to prove the contrapositve of the right side and goes on to say:

> Suppose that $\Delta$ is not satisfiable ... Take any formula $\theta$. Then every truth assignament which satisifies $\Delta$ also satisfies both $\theta$ and $\lnot\theta$!! (Well, you cannot find a truth assignment which gives a couterexample to this last statement, as there aren't any assignments which satisfy $\Delta$!) Thus we have
>
> $\Delta \models\theta$ and $\Delta\models\lnot\theta$
>
> So by (C) we have {EDITOR: (C) refers to the left half of theorem, which has been assumed}
>
> $\Delta \vdash\theta$ and $\Delta\vdash\lnot\theta$
>
> which means that $\Delta$ is inconsistent, as required.

Doesn't the unsatisfiable part ($\models$) essentially mean a contradiction? It's not so much that $\Delta$ satisfies both (it can't satisfy anything by definition!), but rather it is the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)?

But for the contrapositive proof to complete, we have to actually be able to derive contradictions. My question was whether such a thing is actually possible (AND satisfy them!).

Unfortunately in my first version of this question, I had attempted to provide an example where this might fail, but I gave {$C\rightarrow D,D$} $\vdash C$, because I was *also* curious whether an invalid argument that has a satisfiable antecedent was also derivable (I wrote the question over a few days and conflated my thoughts). It was correctly pointed out that "$\Delta$" was indeed satisfiable, and as such a poor example for what was being asked. In retrospect this additional concern seems foolish; I think I (ironically) attempted to affirm the consequent, i.e. simply because $\Delta$ is satisfiable does not mean that it will be consistent (i might have been muddled by the contrapositive inverting their positions).

So, in which case, there's no magic here because **$\Delta \vdash\theta$ and $\Delta\vdash\lnot\theta$** is just a case of **$\Delta = P\land\lnot P$**, and Goldrei should have avoided any talk of satisfying "both $\theta$ and $\lnot\theta$"...?

Comment: $\{ C → D, D \}$ is obviously *satisfiable*; thus, we cannot derive $⊥$.

Comment: He is trying to prove that (C) implies (D) : "We shall prove one half of this and leave the other half as an exercise for you." Thus, the assumption is: "if $Γ \Vdash φ$, then $Γ \vdash φ$" and he proves "if Δ is consistent, then Δ is satisfiable" proving its contrapositive.

Comment: It is not true that $\{ C → D, D \} \vDash C$; try with $D$ true and $C$ false. Also $\{C → D, D \} \vDash ¬C$ does not hold: try with $C$ true and $D$ true.

Comment: In the end, what is the question ? "Are there cases for $Γ⊭θ$, i.e. where not every model for $Γ$ satisfies $θ$ ?" Obviously YES. Consider as $Γ$ the set $\{ p,q,r \}$ and as $\theta$ a contradiction, like: $p \land \lnot p$.

Comment: Maybe you have to check again Def page 74: "Let $Γ$ be a set of formulas and $φ$ a formula involving propositional variables in a set $P$. Then $φ$ is a *logical consequence* of $Γ$, when for all truth assignments $v$ on $P$, if $v(γ) = T$  for all $γ ∈ Γ$, then $v(φ) = T$."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, you somehow divined my actual question! Your first comment triggered a realization of where I went wrong (though i had to go back to work where I had kept some of my research to puzzle it all out). I have updated my question to reflect the full story. Hopefully this helps someone avoid the same pitfall I fell into.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA How do we close this question? Can you answer "yes/no" to the updated version (final sentence).

Comment: "Doesn't the unsatisfiable part (⊨) essentially mean a contradiction?" YES; the gist of the proof is exactly to equate "unsatisfiable" (which is a *semantic* concept) with "inconsistent" (which is a *syntactical* concept). A set of formulas is *unsatisfiable* iff it is *inconsistent*.

Comment: "$Δ⊢θ$  and $Δ⊢¬θ$ is just a case of $Δ=P∧¬P$" NO; obviously, if $Δ⊢θ$  and $Δ⊢¬θ$, by the rules of the calculus we have also $Δ⊢θ∧¬θ$, but not necessarily an *inconsistent* set of formulas mut be (or include) a single formula $P∧¬P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the original question as pointed out by Noah and Mauro. The answer to the (updated) question can be found in the comments, which I am posting here so that I can close the question.

**Answer:**
"Doesn't the unsatisfiable part (⊨) essentially mean a contradiction?" YES; the gist of the proof is exactly to equate "unsatisfiable" (which is a semantic concept) with "inconsistent" (which is a syntactical concept). A set of formulas is unsatisfiable iff it is inconsistent.

"$\Delta\vdash\theta$ and $\Delta\vdash\lnot\theta$ is just a case of $\Delta$ = P $\land\lnot P$" NO; obviously, if $\Delta\vdash\theta$ and $\Delta\vdash\lnot\theta$, by the rules of the calculus we have also $\Delta\vdash \theta \land\lnot \theta$, but not necessarily an inconsistent set of formulas mut be (or include) a single formula P $\land\lnot P$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused: certainly the statement "$\{C\rightarrow D, D\}\vdash\perp$" is **false** in general (that is, depending on what $C$ and $D$ are). For instance, if $C$ and $D$ are each propositional atoms, then the truth assignment making $C$ and $D$ both true is a truth assignment satisfying $\{C\rightarrow D, D\}$ but (trivially) not $\perp$, so "$\{C\rightarrow D, D\}\models\perp$" is **false**, and by the soundness theorem this means that "$\{C\rightarrow D, D\}\vdash\perp$" is equally false.

This issue crops up again further down. You write:

> "If we consider $\{C \rightarrow D, D\} \models C$ and $\{C \rightarrow D, D\} \models \neg C$, it is easy to see that $\{C \rightarrow D, D\}$ is unsatisfiable"

but in general neither $\{C \rightarrow D, D\} \models C$ nor $\{C \rightarrow D, D\} \models \neg C$ is true!

This is a major issue, and I suspect it accounts for the confusion here.

Comment: @NoahScweber yes, there was indeed a huge confusion (on my part) related to the example as you highlighted (see my response to Mauro above). I have updated my question as a result.